# Setting up Angular with an external serverside Backend

Tags: angular

I want to preface all of this by saying I'm a pretty new developer. If there's any clarification needed because my question is not preicse enough I'll gladly provide!

So as part of my current education we're doing something they call pop-up internship where you go to visit a company for a day or two and run through a couple different departments to get a feel for how different companies might tackle some of the daily tasks they encounter.

One company in particular had an app in development that really got me interested. They were building a web application for one of their customers based on the Angular framework from what I understand. The backend/serverside code was written Java. The interesting part is that they used some way to turn the expoted Java-WAR into a file they would include in the Angular project. It allowed them to use the methods, and probably more important the classes, defined in the Java-part of their project directly on the client-side. This seemed like a super interesting concept to me and I would really like to do something like that for an app of my own now.

I don't have any experience with Java, writing mostly little PHP and C# applications so far so I wondered - is a model like this possible to set up with Angular and PHP? If yes, where do I need to look in terms of guidance to set something like that up with my Angular project? What are some key things I need to know before tackling something like this? Is it even worth doing like that?

There's a lot floating in my head right now regarding this because this is kinda exciting to me, any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really sure that they used *Java* classes in Angular? Because Angular is definitely *Javascript* based, and Java !=Javascript.

While I can imagine that they wrote some kind of framework that translates some of their Java classes to JS classes (= generates the .js file content from the .java file content), that would never be done with source code in the compiled WAR-file (WAR-file = zipped, compiled Java .class files).

--

### How I would combine Java + Angular:

--a java project like this:

```
- src/main
  - /java
    - <java packages and classes>
  - /resources/webapp
    - web.xml (configuration of landing point, security, etc.)
    - /angular-generated (empty folder)
```

--an angular project, either completely outside the java project structure or somewhere like src/main/ui

--A (Java) build process that generates the WAR file, triggers the Angular (NodeJS) build process, and then copies the generated Angular HTML + JS files to the /angular-generated folder inside the WAR-file.

(More intelligent build proccess: trigger the Angular build first, copy the files to src/main/resources/angular-generated, and THEN do the Java WAR building).

Great Tutorial example: https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-develop-and-build-angular-app-with-java-backend-87fb603c6e17

---

### How I would combine PHP + Angular:

- make sure that PHP only provides APIs instead of generate frontend HTML
- starting point: index.html
- separate Angular project, dev-configuration for localhost:*php-port*/*url* as backend, prod-configuration for /*url* as backend
- Build process that builds the Angular files and then copies the html to index.html and the other files into the same folder.

Comment: I am 100% sure that they used Java, yes. I was asked to implement something simple during my time there and the process was 1) Implementing it in the server code (Java) 2) exporting the WAR and moving it into the server directory (Wildfly 20.x from what I understand), wait until deployed 3) Start one of the Angular projects NPM scripts to do...something, this here I didn't really get to ask questions about nor look into too much, unfortunately. It seemed to look at the .WAR in the Wildfly directory and generate something from it.

Comment: ah! I am pretty sure that what you describe is the first version of the build process: generate WAR file, deploy WAR file (=copy to server dir), generate Angular HTML (+ JS + CSS + ... files), then copy them to the deployed WAR file. Why do anything with the WAR file? Because the WAR file must also contain all the frontend (HTML + JS + CSS) code to be a working webapp.

Basically: Angular = frontend, Java = backend, WAR = Zip-File that contains both front- and backend

Comment: This sounds like it makes sense, kinda at least. I'm still confused as to how that achieves the fact that I can for example call servicemethods with e.g. Service.loginUser() and have the parameters given type checked, nor the fact that the classes strictly only defined in the Java part of the project useable.

Comment: Angular also has services - mostly, they are used to wrap HTTP calls to the backend. I could imagine that someone did not want to write an Angular service for every Java Servlet, so they devised a way of generating the Service files from the Servlets. However, you would still find the Service files inside the Angular project. Or did they copy the Angular HTML code into a .jsp file??? (JSP is basically HTML + just like in PHP special tags <% %> that signal 'Java Code here'). That would allow you to use Java in what looks like ordinary frontend HTML... But that is just speculation.

Comment: Without seeing both the Angular + Java project, I can only tell you that using Java-Code inside an Angular app is highly irregular, and definitely not anything resembling programming best practices: strict separation of frontend (Angular) and backend (java)

Comment: Unfortunately I can only speak from what I remember. The Java project Structure was a bit off, at least from what I would have expected. You had two main classes, IAppService and AppService, where the former was an interface. It included a link to a "different project", for lack of a better term, in it's build path that included all the classes and general logic. It seemed to be important that all classes which are to be used on the Angular frontend to be imported/defined in AppService and IAppService classes..

Comment: This does tell me, that it is somehow generated from here. The NPM-script that is to be exectued being called "generate-service-reference" also being a big hint at that.

Comment: Yup, that sounds pretty much like they wrote their own (angular) service generation program/script that use the AppService class to know what exactly to translate to JS. You could do similar stuff in PHP, I'm pretty sure, but IMO that's only viable for big projects. Otherwise, you spend more time writing your generator program and setting up that special kind of project structure than you save with it... (definitely not standard).

Comment: Alright, that pretty much wraps up my entire question I think. Thank you very, very much for going through this rather extensive conversation with me, it was quite insightful!